# How to save file to physical path?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have need save a canvas image to my physical address which is located at my C: drive. But I am getting

> The given path's format is not supported.

This is how I doing it.

```
string path = @"C:\tmp";

        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd");
        date = date.Replace("-", "");
        string pathstr = Path.Combine(path, "JobData", "JSAttachments", date, jobsheetno);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathstr);

        string sketchData = Session["SketchData"].ToString();

        if (sketchData != "")
        {

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sketchData.Split(',')[1]);
            sketchname = "Sketch" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".jpeg";
            sketchname = sketchname.Replace("/", "");
            sketchpath = Path.Combine(pathstr, sketchname);
            using (var imageFile = new FileStream(sketchpath), FileMode.Create)
            {
                imageFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                imageFile.Flush();
            }

        }
```

The sketchpath string looks like this

> C:\tmp\JobData\JSAttachments\180116\18011978\Sketch16012018 3:50:50 PM.jpeg

Comment: Just like the exception message states there are characters that are not supported. In your case the `:` character. Next time if you get this message copy/paste the file name you are trying to use into the name of a file (ie. try some troubleshooting). This would also immediately yield the same error.

Comment: yup. That's the issue. Now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using unsupported characters within the file path. `:` (colon) is not allowed, you have to replace the `DateTime.Now.ToString()` with a different format that is allowed.

This is a better solution:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-dd--HH-mm-ss")
```

It still ensures your files will be sortable by name and readable by user

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, the `DateTime.Now.ToString()` returns a string like `16012018 3:50:50 PM` where the colons are not supported by the filesystem.

Use a format specifier like you did on the second line.